# draw line between select points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to draw lines between select points on a ggplot scatterplot.

The data look like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = c('par1', 'par1', 'par2', 'par3', 'par4', 'par5', 'par6'),
  site = c('site1', 'site1', 'site1', 'site1', 'site2', 'site3', 'site4'),
  age = c('20', '20', '25', '34', '27', '31', '29'),
  target = c('par6', 'par4', NA, 'par5', NA, NA, NA)
)
```

Basically, if a given `id` variable has a value in the `target` variable -- which will also exist in `id` -- I'd like to draw a line between the values.

The code for the basic scatterplot is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=id, y=age, color=site)) +
  geom_point()
```

I'd like to modify this so the plot ultimately looks something like
[the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVPpD.png).

I believe the answer may lie in the `group` aes argument and `geom_line()`, but am not grasping how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_segment` gives the line segments like you asked for, but you have to find the values for the segments.

Following code gives me the plot like one you described.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  id = c('par1', 'par1', 'par2', 'par3', 'par4', 'par5', 'par6'),
  site = c('site1', 'site1', 'site1', 'site1', 'site2', 'site3', 'site4'),
  age = c('20', '20', '25', '34', '27', '31', '29'),
  target = c('par6', 'par4', NA, 'par5', NA, NA, NA)
)

plt <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data, mapping=aes(x=id, y=age, color=site))

new_d <- data %>% select(id,target) %>% filter(!is.na(target))
new_d$y <- data$age[match(new_d$id,data$id)]
new_d$ey <- data$age[match(new_d$target,data$id)]

plt + geom_segment(mapping=aes(x=new_d$id,y=new_d$y,xend=new_d$target,yend=new_d$ey))
```

Outputs this

[image: ggplot output]